# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/22419).

Comment: [Link to the last version](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015). Popular results include detexify, OEIS, arXiv, Geogebra, MITOCW, Proof Wiki, and so on.

Comment: Can we put a link to math.SE, or the meta.MSE, or even this specific page? Or do we want to avoid strange loops like that? Also, can we put an ad which advertises all those sites which do not advertise themselves?

Comment: Follow up on [last year's trivia note](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015#comment69233_19014):  this post Id is 22419,  compared to last year's 19014; the one before it was 11920. This meta was much more quiet in 2015 than in 2014.

Comment: @Normal I actually keep track of the meta number changes just to see how meta activity goes each year across the network, haha.

Comment: Could you please clarify if an old add can be reposted "as is." [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment884976_272563) on [meta.se] to me suggests this is the case.

Comment: @quid The comment refers to paid ads. When asked "will Community ad submissions need to comply to this new size?" Abby replied [yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment885010_272563).

Comment: @Normal I had read that. I do not find it quite clear (it could mean new submissions need to comply). I'd rather assume HDE's original comment to which the one I quote is a reply had all ads in mind. It may well be as you say, but then I'd find the comment there a bit misleading.

Comment: Also relevant is [this reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment885010_272563) to [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment884977_272563).

Comment: [DaRT](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/), [Groupprops](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/), [Vector Field Online Graphing](https://kevinmehall.net/p/equationexplorer/vectorfield.html), [Math Portal at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics), [Math books in Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Subject:Mathematics), comes to my mind, and [sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/library-marketing.html) is missing! (I don't know how this works, posting few  suggestions in case someone is inspired to add them!)

Comment: Are you still planning to update 40KB size limit to 150KB? I could do it myself, but...

Comment: Two of the ads, when I hover over them, produce the hover-text `Tagline to show on mouseover` (copied-and-pasted from the format in the question). A third produces the hovertext `enter image description here` (which is what the software puts as the default description when you use the button to add an image to answer). Can these be fixed?

Comment: What about [Desmos](http://www.desmos.com/calculator)? I think this is a tool that could be very useful for Math.SE, but I don't know how to create a suitable image for the ad.

Comment: The [2015 campaign post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015) should be marked as a duplicate of this post.

Answer (score 54):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [Repost from last year.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19017)

Comment: dimensions requirements have changed since then...

Comment: @GrigoryM yes, [but](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment884976_272563)

Comment: Brand new Detexify ad image =). [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/detexify%20ad%202016.svg)

Comment: @Alenanno Double-size ads are allowed and get automatically shrunk; they display better on retina displays. See the specs on the question.

Comment: @E.P. Ah right, I forgot!

Comment: @Normal Gah! good catch, I'll get on it.

Comment: @Normal The 300px version gets the file size right. I'll just leave it like this.

Comment: @E.P. thanks that's great! You do not by any chance feel like making one of OEIS too? :-)

Comment: @quid I'll put it on the list, but the list is long and that's on the bottom, I'm afraid ;-). I'd much rather you guys advertised the DLMF, though that is an enormous fight against their terrible graphical identity.

Comment: @E.P. And then... SE is going to change the file size requirement back to  150KB, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273271

Comment: @Normal Good catch. Thanks for pinging me.

Comment: @quid [There you go](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22442/30935).

Answer (score 49):

[image: The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences]

Comment: Posted separately to [the port from last year](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22424/30935) because I don't want to hijack its high score. You're free to change the sequence if you want, the [SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/oeis%20ad%202016.svg) can be edited in Inkscape.

Comment: Thanks for the graphics. I would certainly be fine if you "hijacked" the post. But then it is likely more fair if you get  the post. I will leave the other up until that one gets over the threshold.

Comment: The old OEIS ad linked to [the sequence shown in it](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C3%2C6%2C2%2C7%2C13%2C20%2C12%2C21%2C11%2C22%2C10%2C23). Perhaps a link to https://oeis.org/A005150 might work here?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Gah! That was the original intention but it got dropped somewhere along the way. Fixed now.

Comment: The OEIS already has its logo. It' displayed on each page of oeis.org/wiki/. @E.P.

Comment: @Max Indeed it does. And you're welcome to submit a separate ad with it if you feel it's important. In the meantime I'll thank you if you leave my original design alone.

Comment: No offense intended. I don't know how the system of Community Promotion Ads work, but I don't think that in any (legal) framework anyone from "outside" has the right to "create" (and publish) a logo for a brand / community / institution / entity that has itself declared what its logo does (and thus has to) look like.
PS: The [2015 promotion ads page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19026/71204) featured the "correct" official OEIS logo.

Comment: Addendum: To start with, let me say that I approve & appreciate advertising for OEIS! 
2nd PS: Now I understand that these are "ads", not "logos". I'm not an expert on the subject, but I'm just surprised that an entity can be advertised for without any official from them knowing about.

Comment: The 2015 ads page has different dimensions so we cannot reuse that file. These are ads and not logos, so I certainly don't see the problem. If OEIS have any issues with this ad, they're obviously welcome to get in touch and I for one will take any objections they have extremely seriously. Similarly, if you have any legal comments beyond vague conjectures, I'll be interested in hearing them. Other than that, as I said, if you want the OEIS ad to feature the official logo (instead of just the name in plain text) you're welcome to propose alternatives.

Answer (score 46):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: @KevinBrown I reused the advertisement of [2014](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11927/154545) and [2015](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19023/154545). I can't find a bigger picture and I think that the other [logos](https://www.google.be/search?q=logo+geogebra&espv=2&biw=1185&bih=657&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR-aH48rHKAhXC6xQKHcw2AngQsAQIIQ) are much less nice (they are somehow less descriptive). I might take the time to build a new similar one with higher resolution next week.

Comment: @KevinBrown I included it. // Surb: I hope you don't mind. In any case I suppose you know how to undo it. :-)

Comment: @quid & Surb: Thanks for the edits! The figure in the middle is a screenshot I made for the [original 2012 ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012/3391#3391), precisely because I felt that it needed something more descriptive than just a logo. If you want to tweak things further, you might find the [.xcf](http://vyznev.net/misc/math.SE_community_ad_geogebra.xcf.gz) and [.ggb](http://vyznev.net/misc/trianglepoints.ggb) files linked from the 2012 ad useful.

Answer (score 40):

[image: arXiv.org: the leading open access eprint repository]

Comment: Edited version of [this 2014 Physics ad](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/posts/5266/revisions). [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arXiv%20ad%202016%202.svg).

Comment: There is too much negative space on the top part. You should move the division line to somewhere around half rather than what I estimate is 7/12th the height.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not sure where the "should" comes from. The ad looks fine to me, and there will always be a sizable amount of blank space, so I don't see that it's terrible to have that space white instead of gray. I was going for a cleaner aesthetic this time but maybe there are sound design principles why it would be better the way you suggest, in which case I would be interested to know what those are. In any case, the source is suitable and your modification is easy to implement so you're welcome to post a version of your own.

Comment: The "should" comes from the understanding that everything I say, especially things about design, is an opinion which you may or may not agree with. I have no intentions of posting a second ad, that would be silly and even confusing. An alternative is to push the "arXiv.org" up so the space above it shrinks, but the ratios between the colors remain the same.

Comment: @Asaf As I said, if it really bothers you then you're welcome to make your own version, but I'm happy with this ad as is and I won't be implementing any changes.

Comment: Asaf is right: the proportions are terrible. The version at the 2014 Physics link are much better.

Comment: To add another opinion: I quite like the open space above the arXiv, somehow symbolizing free, abundant etc (in contrast to the earlier incarnation that was somewhat bottom heavy with that large gray foundation, looking more static). Though if there were slightly less I think it would still  work. What I find not optimal is only the positioning of the text in the the gray as it seems too close to the other text or in any case is not vertically centered.

Answer (score 31):

[image]

Comment: [tex.se] is an awesome site, but I am not sure what the point of advertising it on [math.se] would be. I can see some point in advertising newish or smallish SE-sites, but neither is true for this one.

Comment: @quid I disagree: There has been a lot of interest in Latex on the main site (1,500 questions), and *a lot* of question on TeX SE are about using Maths (equations, plots, etc).

Comment: Your comment does not answer my remark at all. Do you believe there is a relevant number of active users of this site that do not know about [tex.se]? Would you also support an advertisement of SO? Further, it might mainly drive low-quality/off-topic content to [tex.se] such as question about MathJax.

Comment: @quid Why are you only thinking of the regulars? There are always new users and casual visitors who might Google about it and notice the ad.

Comment: To answer the questions directly I assume that a user new to (one site of) the SE network will notice that there are other sites and then will have a look if there might be something they care about. The main point of advertising SE sites in my mind is to make regular users of one site aware of new sites and maybe to give some exposure to small sites, as I explained above. The case that somebody stumbles over this site then sees the tex.se add then goes there and does something relevant seems a bit marginal to me. Maybe you could eventually answer my questions too.

Comment: @quid Sorry, I'm not always on this question. Anyway, the point of ads is to advertise other sites. Smaller sites will benefit more from that, sure, but I don't think there is a rule about what sites you can or cannot advertise. I felt that Math was particularly related to TeX since there are really a lot  of Maths-related questions on the site, precisely 14,373 at this moment, so that's why I posted the ad. Besides, merely posting the ad here doesn't guarantee it will be used, it needs to be accepted by the community first. Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: You replied to a comment containing two questions with a counter question rather than to answer them. So not being on this question can hardly have been the reason. But well. You still do not really answer them, but I guess the last comment is as good an answer I will get, so I'll leave this now.

Comment: @quid What counter question? It seems like you don't want any answer, but want me to say something in particular. And by the way, what I'm doing isn't part of the topic.

Comment: I asked [two questions in this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/community-promotion-ads-2016/22422?noredirect=1#comment87983_22422) You answer with another question rather than to answer them. I have no further interest in this discussion.

Comment: @quid I answered the first one and I felt your second question was sarcastic, considering SO's traffic which is not even comparable to TeX, so there was no point in answering that one.

Comment: Where/what is the answer to the first question?

Comment: @quid [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/community-promotion-ads-2016/22422?noredirect=1#comment87985_22422). But let me rephrase it: I suppose many regulars know about the site, because they know the network. But many new users don't know about it, for whatever reason, not to mention the many visitors who might happen to view this site and then see the ad. I don't think that's something to underestimate. You can disagree of course, but that's how I feel about this matter.

Comment: That was not an answer. But now it is. Thanks.

Comment: @quid glad we could clarify.

Comment: A pedantic remark, but I think the slogan would be better without a question mark. In fact, I wouldn't use any punctuation at all: Beautiful Equations Typeset Beautifully

Answer (score 30):

[image: Sage Mathematical Software Environment]

Comment: Nice new community promotion ad for SageMath!

(Previous versions:
[2015](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19044)
[2014](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11949)
[2013](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6964)
[2012](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3334))

Answer (score 28):

[image: History of Science and Mathematics at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/hsm%20ad%202016.svg), working off of [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Diophantus_title_I_1621.jpg).

Comment: Much better than last year's version.

Comment: @Normal. Thanks :-). I wanted to do something like [the cover of Spivak's calculus on manifolds](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TQkRk.jpg) but it was beyond me. I think this does a good job, though.

Comment: Fermat's Last theorem in the margin?

Answer (score 21):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: [Zipped source - Inkscape SVG and Mathematica notebook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/dlmf%20ad.zip)

Answer (score 20):

[image: cryptography.stackexchange.com]

Comment: I think this ad would be welcome on [cs.SE] as well.

Comment: @Raphael Now, that seems to be a nice idea indeed. [Done!](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1290/9510) Thank you for the heads-up.

Answer (score 19):

[image: GAP - Group, Algorithms and Programming]

Comment: Updated http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19025/70316 to new requirements

Answer (score 19):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Design elements shamelessly stolen from [academia.se]. [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/academia%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: Stolen for [cs.SE](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1206/98), thanks!

Comment: @Raphael I didn't realize the CS site had graduated, that's good to know. Feel free to pilfer, though attribution is always nice :).

Comment: I linked all the copies to the posts I took them from. If you want to be credited by name, I can arrange that of course! (Yup, we are with the big boys now. Once our design is up, I hope we'll soon get our own community ad I can spread over the network.)

Comment: The link is plenty. And congrats.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty happy about things coming full circle for [cs.SE]! =]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Comment: I am a big Overleaf fan but should make it clear that this is a for-profit service with a paid component (though one can use it for free, like I do), since some people objected to that last year.

Answer (score 17):

[image: SageMathCloud Online Computing Environment]

Answer (score 16):

[image: The Cost of Knowledge - join the Elsevier boycott and take back our scientific publishing!]

Comment: I'm curious to know the reason for the downvotes. I expected this one to be a best fit for academia and on second place this site, but apparently not.

Comment: I do not want this promoted, as I do not think it something good.

Comment: @quid What an insightful argument, thanks!

Comment: @pintoch I am not sure how to read your comment.  Anyway, the point of my comment was simply to record that I downvote this because I have a low opinion of the thing to be promoted. This is in stark contrast with my downvote on the tex.se proposal, where I have a very high opinion of the to be promoted thing but do not believe in the usefulness of promoting it here. Put differently I agree the add is fitting in principle, it is also nicely done, but it is just not something I want to  promote at all. To explain why I think so, I do not think this is the place.

Comment: @quid After clicking through and reading the opinions of those involved in the boycott, I'd really like to hear your opinion, but I agree that this comment area is not the place, nor probably M.SE main or meta. If you do write about it somewhere, please link it here.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I just lost a long comment, maybe it was not meant to be I reply.  Very briefly: the page seems not even updated regularly, a "new" saying "last month" yet it seems it was in April. Also I miss the formulation of a goal.

Comment: Also the comparison of journal prices seems done in a biased way; I had not even realized this before. If one compares general top-ish journals there is an obvious choice for the Elsevier journal to consider, Advances. Why is the prize of Advances not mentioned but  rather that of some three unnamed journals whose chracteristics are not at all comparable as far as I could tell? Could it be because it is only around 0.40 per page (data from same year if I got it right) and this would not seem all that outrageous against 0.26 of JAMS and even a good prize relative to Acta and  more so Invent?

Comment: Sure Annals would still be quite a bit cheaper, but they also have still longer papers on average which simplifies things.  Yes it is not only the price it says  but it is the first point in the boycott and a main argument to "sell" the thing. Finally while this not my main issue see some comments on https://gowers.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/a-new-open-access-venture-from-cambridge-university-press/ especially those of Mel Nathanson. Let me also say that there are various good activities around this but that boycott itself is not thought through, and there are some oddities too around it. @Mar

Comment: @quid Thanks for sharing. If you do find similar activities be sure to pop them here and I'll be happy to cook up some graphics for them for this thread.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Computational Science at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/scicomp%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 11):

[image: Desmos: Online Graphing Calculator]

Comment: I think it would be good to add a short text explaining what's this and/or why it may be useful (for example, "free online graphing calculator") to explain the reader why they may be interested in clicking on the advert.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Sure, except that I'm not so good at graphics. 'Paint' is probably the epitome of my skills. Please do edit the image as you see fit.

Comment: It ought to say something like "free online graphing calculator with derivatives, integrals, parametric, polar, and more".

Answer (score 1):

[image: Discover our universe]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Digital Open Access Identifier - a DOI resolver that prioritizes open access]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/doai%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: There is a typo in the word "Access"...

Comment: @Rahul Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Now there is an overlap between the I and the period in the big "DOAI.io" text...

Answer (score 0):

[image: A math-aware search engine for Mathematics Stack Exchange.]

Comment: That's a bad start! :) Read the conditions in the question once more: they say that, in particular, the image should *not* be an animated GIF. Quickly change your image, then, if you don't want your post to get downvoted. Make sure that your image satisfies the other requirements, too.

Comment: Sorry the uploaded image is not the required size, and it is an animated GIF. I found this thread just a hour ago, had no time to make an image meets the requirement, also having some work to do. This is a math-aware search engine, if it gets enough votes I will consider to make a required promotion image and replace the current.

Comment: @AlexM. Hi Alex, see you again. I will try to make a required image when I get time. Sorry.

Comment: @WeiZhong If you plan to replace this by a different image later, deleting your answer until then - and undeleting it after the edit - might be a reasonable thing to do. (As explained by  Alex M., it is possible that if the post stays in current form for too long, it might get downvoted.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you Martin, I just want more potential users to see it, this is why I grab an existing image and paste it here. It is passing 1 am Beijing time, I have to sleep. Promise you to replace it later. If it gets downvoted, it is fine.

Comment: The year is almost over. If I were you I'd wait for the next year and then produce a post according to the then current specifications. (They may or may not change.)

Comment: People won't see the ad on the main site until it gets at least a certain number of votes. I actually meant for you to wait until the meta post for next year's ads, which should be about a month from now. But please follow the rules as some people are a stickler for them. If you notice, the ad I made for Graph (purely because I find it very useful) also got downvoted for no apparent reason. @MartinSleziak: If you know the reason, please tell me, but I seriously can't be bothered too much if people reject useful tools without even trying them.

Comment: @user21820 In this case it is not only "follow the rules - otherwise you might get downvotes". It is also "follow the rules - otherwise the ad will not be displayed in the sidebar" (even if it has enough upvotes). As far as the downvote of your post is concerned, I do not know. I did not try the link myself - however, you cannot be sure whether the downvoters tried it or not.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yep, I don't know whether they tried it, but I suspect so, since I see nothing so bad about it (GPL, fast, small, accurate). And my comment was "X if Y" and is still true even if "Y" is false. Heheh... =P

Comment: @user21820 Anyway, as I said I do not know why some user decided to downvote the answer you mentioned. Asking about the reasons for the downvotes and discussing the possible reasons would probably be better in the comments *under that answer*. If not for other reason, at least we would not ping Wei Zhong with stuff which is unrelated to their post.

Comment: @quid When will the next year's thread be posted?

Comment: @user21820 Your program looks great, my guess is your border is colored gray instead of black as required.

Comment: @MartinSleziak My search engine gets the least downvoted, well, better than I thought :P 
But to keep my promise, I spend some time and replace image to meet the requirement(at least with my best effort).

Comment: @AlexM. Just want to thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Let's hope that those who downvoted the animated GIF will come back to retract their votes.

Comment: You can check the timestamps from earlier years [meta-tag:community-ads] You'll see that initially it was begining of December; then January 1st, and this one mid January.  It's not clear what'll happen for 2017, but I think the mid January was rather an outlier as the format was changed. Anyway, it should be december or early janaury

Comment: @WeiZhong: Well the instructions didn't say the border must be black. Anyway there's a spelling error in your ad! I'll try to remember to upvote your ad for 2017, so just wait around and see when the meta post comes up. =)

Comment: @quid Thanks, that is really helpful.

Comment: @user21820 You are right, so now I am also curious why your work gets downvoted. I agree it would be nice that people left some feedback in comments to help us improve. Anyway, I will correct my typo the next time I post that image. Wish both of us good luck in the upcoming AD post. Thank you for supporting my work.

Comment: @WeiZhong: You're welcome. Although I haven't had much need to use your work yet, I can readily imagine its immense usefulness compared to Google and Math SE's inbuilt search engine! Thank you and all the best!

Comment: It would be best to simply delete this answer and start a new one, since the prior animated gif attracted downvotes, which are preventing the software from getting the exposure it deserves.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for your suggestion, this post already gets pretty old, so forget about this one and let me try posting another for the next AD.

Comment: @WeiZhong Ok, please don't let the downvotes dissuade you. Your software will prove quite valuable to many users. The downvotes are probably simply because users don't want to be distracted by animated ads. Also keep in mind that Meta is far from a representative sample of the main site.

Comment: @BillDubuque I will not easily give up on this project, I myself believe its usefulness regardless what others think. That being said, my biggest pride is actually I have open-sourced this search engine, so you do not need to worry about this project fading away, as long as someone feels it is useful, he/she will host this search engine (hopefully open for public access too). Anyway, I am really thankful for your comments here, it is really a good encouragement, thank you!

Comment: @WeiZhong Great to hear that, and many kudos to you for making it open source.

Comment: @user21820 [Community Promotion Ads for 2017](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25812/community-promotion-ads-2017) has been posted, do not hesitate to post your AD proposal, give it a shot again!

Comment: @WeiZhong: Thanks for your message! Hope your math search engine ad gets shown! =) I don't see anything in the rules against my previous attempt, so I'll just repost it. I find both Geogebra and Graph equally useful in my mathematical work, but perhaps people prefer Geogebra.

Comment: @user21820 Thank you. I did not know Graph is not your own work, anyway, if you are OK with the previous Graph AD proposal and want to share with everybody this time, I can help and post it again.

Comment: @user21820 Sure, I just see your edited comment, so take your time and repost it, good luck this time!

Answer (score -4):

[image: An open source graphing software]

Answer (score -6):

[image: SciRate]

Comment: Edited form of the [earliest SciRate ad I know of](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5982/8563). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/scirate%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score -8):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Comment: [First arXiv Analytics ad I know of](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6127/8563). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arxiv%20analytics%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: So... Has more than a single review been written yet?

Comment: I'm not sure - I don't run the service. (It does look like there's a single review and not a lot of movement on the reviews front since this time two years ago, though.) You'll have to ask soliton, over on Physics, what the site's status is.

Comment: @najib-idrissi Sorry for my late reply. There is only a single review and the review section does not attract much attention. The majority of our users are graduate students, who do not show much interest in writing reviews.  Any ideas on how to encourage users to write reviews? Could you provide some reviews?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi We need the promotion ads to reach out to more users.

Answer (score -9):

[image: Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs]

Comment: What's that for? It is not clear to me what is advertized.

Comment: i contend that this is an amazing ad, helps out in making problems

Answer (score -11):

[image: arXiv.org - over a million papers, free to access]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arXiv%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: I find it ironic that this one has even more whitespace than the one [Asaf was complaining about](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22419/50776#comment88039_22427).

Comment: Yeah, this one is not a happy ad anywhere. Oh well.

Answer (score -12):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width (to despise, as it were)! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but should the answer display an image?

Comment: I wonder at which point the Twitter bot will "return to the source". From what I understand, these bots are no longer maintained.

Comment: @user yes, the code that is prescibed in OP will display the image.  It should display the proposed add as it will be seen. See the last incarnation for examples. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015

Comment: @quid Right, I know - I just meant that this particular answer is not displaying any image (at least for me).

Comment: @user it displays an image for me.

Comment: @quid Huh, that's strange. I see no image in Firefox 44.0b8, but I do in IE10 and Chrome 47.

Comment: @user I see it in Firefox, different version though.

Comment: @quid Weird. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @quid: Neither am I seeing any image...

Comment: @T.Bongers do you see the images in other answers? (And welcome back. :-) )

Comment: @quid Every single one except this one (Thanks!)

Comment: https://twitter.com/stackmath shows 551 follower and it seems that 99% of tweets are announcements of bounties. I don't see the point of promoting bounties via Twitter and down voted this (same as in previous years). Offering a bounty does not necessarily imply that the question is of an interest to a wider audience. For the twitter account, I'd rather like to see links to high quality questions and answers, and indeed some links to questions on the life of the website from Meta. If this will happen, I am happy to upvote this ad.

Comment: My comment have been heard - thanks! (see https://twitter.com/stackmath/status/690676802667286528 ). I can not upvote it unless it's edited, though. Maybe remove dot after "grow"?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Quite frankly, it doesn't matter whether you upvote this or not: the Twitter ad has always been double-digit  downvoted. It's a local tradition.